# What's scatter files in .NET assembly

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I'm compiling a .NET application and in diagnostic output of `MSBuild` I see mentions of scatter files (from referenced assembly). Searching for some information around interwebs brought nothing useful. Only reference I found was [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.tasks.resolveassemblyreference.scatterfiles.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in `Microsoft.Build.Tasks`.

My question is what's this feature doing? Where I can "see" it?

Answer (score 1):

As the link mentions it is reserved for internal use. I couldn't find anything actually using it though. From the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/search?p=1&q=scatter&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) it seems scatter files are just a list of arbitrary files which serve as extra dependencies for assemblies. When copying those assemblies (e.g. to the output directory of a project being built when the CopyLocal flag is set) the scatter files will be copied as well.

Comment: That's what I saw in behavior. My DLL is 3rd party assembly and it's somewhat in it. So I suppose there's a way to do it. But I was not able to find nothing specific for it.